# Compile - Syntax Error: When toggling select filter with If Statement

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

it's me again - I'll get to know this language better eventually.

Basically - I have a big table of data that has autofilter on - range "$B$5:$Z$1697"

However, there is an additional filter on the R column that I want to be toggled on or off.

Therefore I need an If statement that says when the additional filter is on, remove, whereas, if the filter is not on at the time you press the button - apply it.

I've played around with this and watched more videos that I care to admit. However, there must be something I'm overlooking or don't understand.

The code works up until the Else line, which returns:

> "Compile Error, Syntax Error".

Can anyone explain what's happening?

```
If Sheets(4).Range("$B$5:$Z$1697").AutoFilter(Field:=17, Criteria1:="=") = True Then
    'If there specific filter on column R is on then

    Sheets(4).Range("$B$5:$Z$1697").AutoFilter Field:=17
    'Turn off that filter.

Else: Sheets(4).Range("$B$5:$Z$1697").AutoFilter(Field:=17, Criteria1:="=")
'Else, if the filter is off, turn it on.

End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: I have corrected the code, amending this ELSE line to this

```
Else: Sheets(4).Range("$B$5:$Z$1697").AutoFilter(Field:=17, Criteria1:="=") = True
```

However, when I run this now it means that it turns the filter On and then Off again with one push of the button. How do I make it so it onl makes on change at a time.

I.e. if the filter is on when the button is pressed it ONLY turns it off.

And vice versa

Comment: Hey there! :) Cheers, I just tried it and it returns a Compile Error: Expected: Expression?

Comment: Don't forget to refer to a wb and ws for each range object. That includes the `Sheets()` object.

Comment: Why use ':' instead of just placing the code for that else statement in a new line?

Comment: I am really sorry, I am not sure what bit you are referring to? Do you mean the blank criteria in the Else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to toggle a filter on/off is to use an `ActiveX Toggle button`. When the toggle button is clicked (enabled) your filter will be applied, when clicked again (disabled) your filter is removed. Change the name of the `toggle button` and  `Criteria1` to meets your needs.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    'when selected(enabled) the filter for Col "Q" will be enabled 
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        Sheets(4).Range("$B$5:$Z$1697").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="2"
    Else
    'when selected again(disabled) the filter for Col "Q" will be Disabled 
        Sheets(4).Range("$B$5:$Z$1697").AutoFilter Field:=17
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MimiBeard I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

***This is NOT a complete answer, but I can't fit all this into a comment...***

I've found that continually using compound references to refer to different objects within Excel can really give me headaches. Using intermediate objects doesn't impose any significant performance penalty at all, so I am in the habit of breaking down the compound reference into a series of intermediate objects. Doing this gives me at least two advantages:  1) I can examine the intermediate objects to make sure of the data I **think** should be there, and 2) I get far fewer syntax errors because each step gets validated.

So, while I can't check if this is correct since I can't access your data, your logic could look like this

```
Sub Example()
    Dim fourthWS As Worksheet
    Dim filteredData As Range
    Set fourthWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
    Set filteredData = fourthWS.Range("$B$5:$Z$1697")

    Dim dataIsFiltered As Variant
    dataIsFiltered = filteredData.AutoFilter(Field:=17, Criteria1:="=")

    If dataIsFiltered Then
        '--- turn off the filter
        filteredData.AutoFilter Field:=17
    Else
        '--- turn on the filter
        filteredData.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="="
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MimiBeard see how Peter has constructed his If..Else statement? It allows for a better overview

Comment: @TimStack Ooooh, I get you now! Sorry I didn't see that right away, guess it takes clear eyes!

Comment: Thank you Peter,I'm trialing it now and it is saying that the Set dataIsFiltered =
line needs an object I will keep playing

Comment: It was my mistake. The `AutoFilter` line returns a `Variant` type that is used as a boolean. I've fixed the code in the example above.