# VBA Toggle Button For Filter not Running Second Condition

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have asked a very similar question to this before on another project, therefore I have already gone through their suggestions and attempted to implement them in the code here. However, none of it is working...
Here's the question for reference: 
[Compile - Syntax Error: When toggling select filter with If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239377/compile-syntax-error-when-toggling-select-filter-with-if-statement)

I don't know whether that's just an unnoticed error or something specific about the objects and syntax I don't know.

Basically, what I want here is to have a toggle button - when you press it it alternates between filtering the Q column to show only the not accepted jobs, and to reset that filter so it shows all jobs.

Somehow in my code it only plays the IF portion of the statement and not the Else. 
It's not the filter code lines itself as if I move the other to be the first statement it runs without errors, other than it doesn't play the else statement on the next press.

Can anyone help

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()


If ShowRejected.Value = True Then

   Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
    "Not Accepted"
    'when selected(enabled) the filter for Col "Q" will be enabled, showing only the jobs that have been rejected by partners
Else:

    Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12
    'when selected again(disabled) the filter for Col "Q" will be Disabled, therefore showing all jobs
   End If
End Sub
```

Edit - After making changes to my sheet it works

Comment: Shouldn't `ShowRejected.Value` be `ToggleButton1.value` ?

Answer (score 0):

Like say in comment, you have to `ShowRejected` by the name of your `button`.

The code below works fine :

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
   MsgBox "if"
Else:
   MsgBox "else"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The Button was called ShowRejected. 

Just tried this code and it's not working. If shows me the "If" message but never the "else"

Comment: How the name of your button can be `ShowRejected` and the name of your function `ToggleButton1_Click` ?
Maybe try to restart your Excel because this code works fine.